# Prove $f(x)f^{-1}(x)=g(x)g^{-1}(x)⇒f(x)=g(x)$ or $f(x)=g^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus

When we donote by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ the functions whose domain of definition and range are $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $f(1)=g(1)=1$, prove that $f(x)f^{-1}(x)=g(x)g^{-1}(x)⇒f(x)=g(x)$ or $f(x)=g^{-1}(x)$ is true.

I tried to prove by differentiating both sides, but I can’t. I have no longer ideas. Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

By evaluating your function at $x = f(y)$ we get

$f(f(y))=g(f(y))\cdot g^{-1}(f(y))$

or in other notation:

$f \circ f = (g \circ f) \cdot (g^{-1}\circ f)$

Now it is clear to see that the identity holds if  $f=g$ or $f=g^{-1}$ , one of the right handsides become the identity function , and the other $f \circ f$

Comment: If $f=g$ or $f=g^{-1}$ the proof is trivial, but how do you show that one of those cases **must** be true?

Comment: It’s necessary conditions but is it also sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is tacitly assumed here that $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ exist as bona fide functions $[0,1]\to[0,1]$. But in this case it is obvious that
$$f\circ f^{-1}={\rm id}_{[0,1]}=g\circ g^{-1}\ ,$$ 
whatever $f$ and $g$ fulfilling the assumptions. Any pair $f(x):=x^m$, $\>g(x):=x^n$ with natural exponents $m\ne n$ provides a counterexample to the claim in the question.